# Python Tkinter Checkbutton-text Alignment Issue

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am fooling around with GUI programming using Tkinter on python, with the goal being a GUI app which will allow a user to add a task or delete (to be saved to a txt file).

Right now, I am just trying to figure out the basics of adding/removing checkbuttons.

The issue I am having is that when I run the script, the check boxes are not aligned with the text for them. The picture below shows the issue.
[image]

The code used to pull tasks from a txt file and add them as checkbuttons is as follows:

```
tasks = []
        with open(r"C:\Users\patte\Desktop\tasks.txt") as file:
            tasks = file.readlines()
        row = 2
        for task in tasks:
            self.task_checkbox = Checkbutton(self.master,text=task,font=("Arial",12),relief='groove')
            self.task_checkbox.grid(row=row,column=0,sticky=W)
            row+=1
```

Note that row is initialized to 2 as the title and entry bar take up rows 0 and 1. I have tried changing fonts, etc., but the result stays the same.

Any sort of advice or criticism is greatly appreciated.

The full code is as follows:

```
from tkinter import *

class ToDo():
    def __init__(self,master):
        self.master = master        # Geometry and layout when initialized
        master.geometry("800x800")
        master.title("TO DO")
        self.gui_title = Label(self.master,text="Tasks:",font = ("Arial Bold",26))
        self.gui_title.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky=W)

        self.task_entry_label = Label(self.master,text="Enter Task:",font = ("Arial",12))
        self.task_entry_label.grid(row=2,column=0,sticky=W)

        self.task_entry = Entry(self.master)
        self.task_entry.grid(row=2,column=1,sticky=W)
        self.task_entry.focus_set()

        tasks = []
        with open(r"C:\Users\patte\Desktop\tasks.txt") as file:
            tasks = file.readlines()
        row = 3
        for task in tasks:
            self.task_checkbox = Checkbutton(self.master,text=task,font=("Arial",12),relief='groove')
            self.task_checkbox.grid(row=row,column=0,sticky=W)
            row+=1

        self.QuitButton = Button(self.master,text="Quit",font=("Arial Bold",12),command = lambda: self.master.quit())
        self.QuitButton.grid(sticky=SW,row=7)


root = Tk()
Tasks = ToDo(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Thanks!

Comment: Your example would be easier for us to use if it didn't rely on a separate file. Can you hard-code some example data instead of reading it from a file?

Comment: @BryanOakley I believe you just solved it. It is a text file with a line between each entry, and I forgot to remove the \n.